# Integration of spring and bigtable database

Tags: spring-mvc, google-cloud-bigtable

I am learning bigtable now I want to integrate my spring MVC project to bigtable.I searched in internet but I am not get any exact answer.It's like spring boot and bigtable ,hadoop and bigtable,but I need spring MVC and bigtable integration please help me out.

Comment: I submitted a feature request on your behalf: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/486

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a feature request on your behalf:

> https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/486